# Divide data in single column to multiple columns

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, pivot

I have source data like

```
Name Is_Trget
a     Yes
s     No
d     Yes
f     Yes
a     Yes
S     No
```

from this source data expected output is

```
Name Is_Yes Is_No
a    2      0
s    0      2
d    1      0
f    1      0
```

I need count of Yes and No for a specific Name.

Can someone help on this.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT Name, 
       SUM(CASE Is_Trget WHEN 'Yes' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Is_Yes,
       SUM(CASE Is_Trget WHEN 'No' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Is_No
FROM source
GROUP BY Name;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=7e7a8b97ccf941fc8ca9376123e551a5)

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach using `PIVOT`

```
SELECT  Name
,       Is_Yes  = Yes
,       Is_No   = No
FROM YourTable AS A
PIVOT (COUNT(Is_Trget) FOR Is_Trget IN ([Yes], [No])) AS PivotTable
```